# Database importing tables with multiple values using java or sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, csv

i would like to import an csv data from imdb. The file contains following stuff: id, title, release_date, and actors
But in column Actors there are more then one actor stored so it look like

```
id   title   release_date   actor

1     FF7      2015         Vin Diesel|Paul Walker|Jason Statham
```

I know that the actor is a fk from  an actors table which I have to create. If I would like to import that csv how to clear up the csv to import it using java or sql.
It could take to long if I sperate the first three colums from the actors and import the columns and try to import the actor column

Answer (score 0):

Import the entire csv, as is, into a staging table.   Then execute a stored proc to move the data to the desired destination tables.